# p:chart with DateTime axis

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I'm trying to create a line chart using the component `<p:chart>` of the Primefaces 5.1.

And I need the X axis displays the time. Something like this:

[image]

But only against documentation of the old version.

I found several things like:

- [Customize primefaces chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846494/customize-primefaces-chart)
- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23891&p=78637#p78637

But in version 5.1 there is no such tag `<p:lineChart>`, and not even the attribute `extender=""`.

I created my chart based on the showcase:

- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml

But this example does not help much, because it is only working with date. And to complicate are as String. I need the hours.

**I wonder if someone has already created something similar in the newer versions of Primefaces.**

**EDIT:**

Searching a bit more, I found this topic:

- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=40301&p=127330&hilit=p%3Achart+date#p127330

I used the example mentioned it, and I could make it work.

What I could see, when it is a DateAxis is required to set the `axis.setMax()`. At the end looked like this:

[image]

It worked as I needed, but two things I did not understand:

**First:** The reason to be required to set the `axis.setMax()`.

**Second:** What is this pattern used in `axis.setTickFormat("%H:%#M:%S")`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I think now I found a acceptable solution.

The initial problem with the chart was `axis.setMax()`.

And the pattern used in the `axis.setTickFormat` is:

```
Code    Result                  Description
            == Years ==
%Y      2008                Four-digit year
%y      08                  Two-digit year
            == Months ==
%m      09                  Two-digit month
%#m     9                   One or two-digit month
%B      September           Full month name
%b      Sep                 Abbreviated month name
            == Days ==
%d      05                  Two-digit day of month
%#d     5                   One or two-digit day of month
%e      5                   One or two-digit day of month
%A      Sunday              Full name of the day of the week
%a      Sun                 Abbreviated name of the day of the week
%w      0                   Number of the day of the week (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday)
%o      th                  The ordinal suffix string following the day of the month
            == Hours ==
%H      23                  Hours in 24-hour format (two digits)
%#H     3                   Hours in 24-hour integer format (one or two digits)
%I      11                  Hours in 12-hour format (two digits)
%#I     3                   Hours in 12-hour integer format (one or two digits)
%p      PM                  AM or PM
            == Minutes ==
%M      09                  Minutes (two digits)
%#M     9                   Minutes (one or two digits)
            == Seconds ==
%S      02                  Seconds (two digits)
%#S     2                   Seconds (one or two digits)
%s      1206567625723       Unix timestamp (Seconds past 1970-01-01 00:00:00)
            == Milliseconds ==
%N      008                 Milliseconds (three digits)
%#N     8                   Milliseconds (one to three digits)
            == Timezone ==
%O      360                 difference in minutes between local time and GMT
%Z      Mountain Standard Time  Name of timezone as reported by browser
%G      -06:00              Hours and minutes between GMT
            == Shortcuts ==
%F      2008-03-26          %Y-%m-%d
%T      05:06:30            %H:%M:%S
%X      05:06:30            %H:%M:%S
%x      03/26/08            %m/%d/%y
%D      03/26/08            %m/%d/%y
%#c     Wed Mar 26 15:31:00 2008  %a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y
%v      3-Sep-2008          %e-%b-%Y
%R      15:31               %H:%M
%r      3:31:00 PM          %I:%M:%S %p
            == Characters ==
%n      \n                  Newline
%t      \t                  Tab
%%      %                   Percent Symbol
```

- http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html

The model:

```java
private void createDateModel() {
    dateModel = new LineChartModel();
    LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
    series1.setLabel("Series 1");
    series1.set("2014-01-01 00:10:50", 51);
    series1.set("2014-01-01 00:10:51", 22);
    series1.set("2014-01-01 00:10:52", 65);
    series1.set("2014-01-01 00:10:53", 35);
    dateModel.addSeries(series1);
    dateModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Values");
    DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");
    axis.setTickAngle(-50);
    axis.setMax("2014-01-01 00:10:56");
    axis.setTickFormat("%H:%#M:%S");
    dateModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
}
```

And the chart:

```xml
<p:chart type="line" model="#{controller.dateModel}" />
```