# Opacity for data series in PrimeFaces chart

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I want set opacity for data series in my `PrimeFaces` chart, but I can't find in Google how do that. Maybe somebody can help , how set it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize primefaces chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846494/customize-primefaces-chart)

Comment: @JasperdeVries I find solution. When I set series in Java, I can use method `setFillAlpha()`.

Comment: Good! Hopefully the duplicate is also useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem. In Java code I can use method `setFillAlpha()`and pass value of opacity for my chart. For example:
`lineModel.setFillAlpha(0.8)`.