# Primefaces Chart number format

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I want that numbers in my [Primefaces Bar Chart](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml) should be displayed with decimal points (e.g.: 102.456,00).

Is it possible to set number format in a [function extender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846494/customize-primefaces-chart):

```
function ext() {
    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.formatString = "R$ %d ";
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelFormatString = "R$ %d";
}
```

With this function, the numbers are displayed like this: R$10832 | R$25476 etc.
But I want it to be displayed like: R$10.832 | R$25.476 etc.

Is it possible to set it in the function or do I need to set it with [Java Number Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: No, I did not. Any hints ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this solution for thousand separator in bean controller :

```
Axis yAxis = graph.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
yAxis.setTickFormat("%'.0f");
```

So, for your question try `yAxis.setTickFormat("R$%'.0f");`

Comment: Hi! Your solution displays results like 10,000.01; but I need dots for thousands separator and commas for decimal separator, like: 10.000,01.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for a solution in the JQPlot documentation, I found that is possible to set the thousandsSeparator and decimalMark in the Extender, as follows:

```
<script>
            function ext() {
                this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.formatString = "R$%'#.0f";
                $.jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = '.';
                $.jqplot.sprintf.decimalMark = ','; 

            }
</script>
```