# Remove label in Primefaces Line Chart

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces line chart that appears between the graph series its values.
I followed the primefaces documentation, but instead of showing the "LinearChart", it shows "CategoryChart"
I need to disable these labels, how do I do this?
Below image of my chart.

[line graphic - I want to remove the labels that are embedded in the graph lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8crE.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize primefaces chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846494/customize-primefaces-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!
There was the following code in my method ...

```
lcm.setShowPointLabels(true); // lcm is LineCharModel
```

It made appear the labels in line chart.